# Can we use contour integral to compute Fourier Transform to reach a better accuracy numerically?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

The problem is evaluate the integrals as follows: 
$$L(t)=\int_{0}^\infty [a(\omega)-a_\infty]\cos(\omega t)d\omega \quad(1)$$ and
$$L(t)=\int_{0}^\infty b(\omega)\frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega}d\omega\qquad\qquad (2)$$
where $a(0)=a_0$ and $a(\infty)=a_\infty$ and $b(0)=b(\infty)=0$.
Formula (1) shows very slow convergence, but (2) needs to evaluate to quite large $\omega$.

Desperately wondering if both (1) and (2) can be utilized by some smart transformation, like $[\cos(\omega t),\sin\omega t]$...

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean. Is $a(\omega)$ some given function or are you asking in the most general case ? Of course there is no major simplification in the general case (that's why you won't find it in any course on the Fourier transform) but in many special cases there are.

Comment: $a(\omega)$ and $b(\omega)$ are given functions.

Comment: $a(\omega)$  and $b(\omega)$  for both limit ends, i.e., $\omega=0$ and $\omega=\infty$ are known but it is difficult or impossible to known their values when $\omega$ is large.